# Cannot find source of traffic spike

Tags: traffic, scraping

I noticed in my Munin graphs for Apache that there was a large spike in traffic yesterday. However, I have been unable to correlate this with anything on the site.

[image: munin]

Google Analytics does not show any traffic increase. It essentially only counts human users (those with Javascript enabled) so I'm guessing the spike could be from a scraper.

But I checked the Apache logs and the number of requests does not correlate with the Munin output. I ran a few commands to count the number of requests each hour from the logs and it just shows the regular increase, nothing like the spike shown in Munin.

I checked both `other_vhosts_access.log` (which counts the actual websites set up) and `access.log` (counts hits to the IP address, which seems to be mostly dummy connections or security polls).

Where might these extra hits be coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is true, but possibly Apache only logs requests if they are valid http requests?

So if I were to create a whole bunch socket connections to your apache server it would cause new apache processes to spawn, which is what you are looking at in your graph, but if I never send a valid http request and disconnect - or apache times out the connection and it disconnects, possibly that is why you see nothing in the logs.

I wonder if it logs those to an error log.

Comment: Hmm, so does that imply some kind of DoS attack?

Comment: Seems like that could be the case.